# How to join my VM to AAD - select virtual network

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I'm trying to create Windows Server VM joined to the AAD where my Azure Subscription is.

I'm reading [Join a Windows Server virtual machine to a managed domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/join-windows-vm), but I'm stuck on step #6:

[image: VM Virtual Network Settings]

> select the virtual network in which your Azure AD DS-managed domain is
>   deployed. Pick a different subnet than the one that your managed
>   domain is deployed into

There are no virtual networks in the select box and the only options is to create new. But if I create new, then I can't reach the domain controller from the VM.

Comment: If you put it into the same virtual network but different subnet you cannot reach the DC? As long as the machines are in the same VNET you should be able to communicate across subnets.

Comment: But what machines? I only have my VM that I want to join and AAD associated with subscription,

Comment: Oh, I see it now. I have to create AAD Domain Services resource. But is this the only way how to login to the VM using my exititng AAD accounts (that I use to login to azure portal)?

Comment: Yes that is the route you would want to take. Otherwise, you could sync your on premise DC to AAD to merge the accounts. But if you only have an Azure AAD then creating a domain services resource would be the route to take

Comment: Ok, and what if my VM was created in another subscription than the AAD Domain Services. I can't select the righ virtual network then. How do I connect the VM's virtual network to the AAD DS?

Comment: Would you then want to peer the two networks in the 2 subscriptions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-peering-overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using AAD with no other AD on prem or located in Azure, you need to create an [Active Directory Domain Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/) account in order to join VMs to that domain.

Otherwise, if you are syncing your on premise domain to your AAD domain via AD Sync you just need to ensure that the VMs you want to join to the domain have access to the virtual network where the domain is located. This means you can opt to peer virtual networks in Azure or connect the separate networks using a Site-to-Site VPN connection.

For this particular issue, you would go with the Active Directory Domain Services account and put it into a blank subnet in the same Vnet as the Virtual Machines are located. Once this is one, you will be able to connect the VMs to your managed domain.